# How can I transfer old Roots V databse files to new family software?

Tags: data-transfer

Years ago, (and several later computers and widows versions) I used Roots V, I still have all the database files and would like to find a good genealogy program to use them in.BTW, my renewed interest id because of the DNA revolution.)

Answer (score 3):

A quick internet search has a [link](http://rootsusers.org/FAQs/FAQ_R5.html) suggesting that TMG (The Master Genealogist) can import the .pro file from Roots V. TMG has been discontinued but can still be downloaded. You can then transfer from TMG to a currently supported application of your choice.